# How to deal with "Find the error in my GitHub repository" questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

Fairly regularly, I see questions only linking to a GitHub repository saying "Why it does not work?".

Those questions are clearly:

1. Link-only questions
2. Useless for the community as the GitHub repository will be immediately updated when the issue will be resolved
3. Off-topic as it does not provide a MCVE.

---

At the moment, the best thing that can be done is (in my opinion):

1. Warn the user that the question is not properly asked and that code must be included **in the question**.
2. **Vote to close the question as off-topic** if the user still refuses to update the question because "*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.*"

The problem is that the close-vote review queue is [already full](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close), and this question may probably **continue to exist for days and days**.

Here is a [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971308/issue-in-routes-using-ui-router-angularjs) of what I am talking about. Due to the Meta effect the question will probably be closed faster, so here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Jy0.png) of the question/comments.

---

My questions are:

- Do I do it the right way?
- How can we react more quickly than by launching a vote to close this type of question?

Comment: Yes, close voting, either as MCVE or too broad will work,  and down voting are the correct actions. You can always consider to post a `[cv-pls]` in a chat room that are open for this, like I did [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36262366#36262366).. You might want to check the FAQ with our [rules](http://socvr.org/) before posting.

Comment: I agree with rene, either we lack an MVCE, or either the code won't fit in a post and so the answer which make it too broad.

Comment: The other problem is the FGsITW that answer any and all questions posted no matter the quality. They'll go over users' crapfest code searching for the one misplaced semicolon so they can get their repz.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan If the answers on such questions aren't useful they can also be down voted.

Comment: @BSMP The point I was trying to make is the fact they are answered before they can be closed acts as incentive for users to continue to ask these kinds of questions.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Agreed. I think the problem is mostly "how to fix the close-vote review queue?", but I guess this is another question...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I agree, the day before yesterday [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928834/jquery-e-target-e-is-not-defined) one got so much attention, and I simply don't get why nobody else closed it or downvoted it

Comment: @BSMP, yeah `(+2 vote) + (-3 vote) = + 14 rep`. And downvoters get never back their reputation. But that is another topic...

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I still think bad question should be down voted, if only for an eventual answer ban for repeat offenders, but I accept that I'm in the minority here.

Comment: @BSMP, no you are right. Downvoting is very important. I only wanted to show, that our rep whores and FGsITW see some other calculations... Imho a downvote should remove all the reputation from an upvote. Bad content is way to fast upvoted by newbies.

Comment: We have a check that prevents questions which has a link to jsfidle without the actual thing on the site... that ought to help.

Answer (score 17):

Simple close as off topic. The *MCVE* reason is word by word correct:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the
>   shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example.

The problem about the close vote queue having more than 10k items waiting to be reviewed [is an old topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183840/what-can-be-done-about-the-massive-close-votes-queue-on-stack-overflow). However, this should not change how we close or not close questions.

If you start to make an exception for GitHub questions, where would this end?

The only thing I can imagine to make this process faster, is making close vote reviews more attractive. Repeating badges for example.

Comment: _"However, this should not change how we close or not close questions."_ I only have one pedantic thing to say about that: The shear mass of the close vote queue should be taken into consideration when voting/flagging to close borderline content, just because we really don't need to be wasting review votes clicking leave open on borderline posts that irked someone. In this case though, it should certainly be closed.

Comment: Oh you kids and your 10k close queues. When *I* was a kid we had 120k posts in the queue, and we had to review uphill, both ways!

Answer (score 2):

Downvote as "not useful" and vote to close as "missing MCVE": such questions are generally completely useless for future visitors without looking at the link's content and violat at least on part of code requirement - "code ... in the question itself".

Note that downvote is important part as downvoted questions are automatically deleted by Roomba, so even if MCVE close vote ages out the question is likely to get removed.